# Why component not rendering service model?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component where I get filters from service `Settings`:

```
export class OrdersExecutionSidebarComponent {
       public get filters(): _Filter[] {
        return this.settings.filtersRepository.filters;
    }
}
```

Template is:

```
<app-filter [filter]="flt" *ngFor="let flt of filters"></app-filter>
```

Inside children component `app-filter`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-filter',
    templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
    providers: [FilterService],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class FilterComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() filter: _Filter;
}
```

Template is:

```
<span *ngFor="let f of filter.collection">{{f}}</span>
```

Why after changes `filtersRepository.filters` in service `Settings` the component `app-filter` does not renders `@Input() filter`?

Problem is that if data is changed in service it has no effect in children component `app-filter`. So, parent component should push a new data `filters` to
`<app-filter [filter]="flt" *ngFor="let flt of filters"></app-filter>`

**Important remark:**

When chnages happens in service I see console.log here:

```
public get filters(): _Filter[] {
    console.log(this.settings.filtersRepository.filters);
    return this.settings.filtersRepository.filters;
}
```

But `@Input` of children component has no changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that filter is a nested object. When you e.g. add an element to `filter.collection` for Angular it will still be the same object because its object reference does not change.

What you need to do to fix this:

**1) Don't pass filter but only the collections to the child component**

```
export class FilterComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() collections: Collection[];
}
```

**2) Recreate the collections array instead of adding to it**

E.g. if you do something like this, the Angular change detection will not be triggered:

```
// Still the same array!
filter.collection.push(myCollection);
```

While this will work:

```
// New array, therefore Angular will know it has to re-render!
filter.collection = [...filter.collection, myCollection];
```

If you do have to pass the complete filter object to your child, you could in a similar way recreate the filter object when its collections update:

```
filter = {...filter, collection: [...filter.collection, myCollection]};
```

Comment: First way I can not use because I need pass fulle object with collection property and meta data. Second way, where to apply this?

Comment: I appended to my answer - you can also recreate the filter object completely. You have to apply this pattern in the component that holds the filters object, e.g. when adding new filters to it or removing them.

Comment: I can share my settings service, but I dont know where to recreate array

Comment: I got your mind, but I dont know how to apply this in my case

Comment: Could you check my question, I have add my service